# How do I find an upper bound on $z/(z^3+1)$ on a circular path with radius R centred at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to use the estimation theorem,

so I want to find an $M$ such that $|\frac{z}{z^3 + 1}| < M$

I cant seem to work with the $z^3$.

$$|z^3 + 1| \geq |z^3 - 1| $$ is just not true.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use $\lvert a+b\rvert \geqslant \lvert a\rvert - \lvert b\rvert$.

Comment: What Daniel said. Note as well that this comes out different depending on whether $R<1$ or $R>1$...

Comment: Why not let $z=Re^{2\pi it}$ and work with the real variable $t\in[0,1]$?